# Why does a columnbreak between equation environments insert vertical space?

Tags: spacing, environments, multicol

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
        \columnbreak % why does this columnbreak insert vspace?
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered MWE]

Answer (score 1):

You can set, locally, `\multicolsep` to 0pt. However, it would be simpler to use `tabularx`: I propose to define a newcolumn type with  cells contents automatically in the equation environment, making the typing very simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\newcolumntype{E}{@{}>{\compress\equation}X<{\endequation}@{}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
 {\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
        \columnbreak % why does this columnbreak insert vspace?
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
    \end{multicols}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
        \begin{equation} a = a \end{equation}
    \end{multicols}
}
\vspace{4ex}

   {\centering\belowdisplayskip=0pt
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}E@{\enspace}|@{\enspace}E@{}}
    a = a & a = a \\[-1ex]
     a = a & a = a
    \end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inserting an empty line in-front of the `\columnbreak` makes it look the same.

Comment: Inserting 

`\let\oldColumnbreak\columnbreak
\renewcommand{\columnbreak}{\par\oldColumnbreak}`
into the preamble also fixes this for the whole document.

Is that a good idea?